# Is it a good practice to create database, tables and indexes as part of application bootup

Tags: mongodb, microservices, database

Before starting my application I want to verify if my database, collection* and appropriate indexes exists. If not create them, and verify again, and fail on mis match.

Is it a good practice to do as part of application bootup, or should it be done as a separate process ?

(*) I am currently using mongodb, but this question is not limited to one database